# EclipseLink does not work on Netbeans, is this normal?

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, java-ee-6, jta

It'll be weeks that I'm stuck with EclipseLink. I can not persist an object in my database. I use netbeans 7.3. I encountered this problem when I started designing a web application. What follows is the approach I have adopted. It may be that I do without me realize a mistake.

After that netbeans has finished generating the project files I configured the jndi. Then I converted automatically with netbeans, the database tables in entity object.
[here is the link](http://pastebin.com/GhGmu6tc)

then, from these classes, I created their [JPAController](http://pastebin.com/Qfj2cFaQ) . (Always automatically with netbeans)

and finally, as a test, I just instantiate the description of "Outils" and leave the fields empty id. Since the latter automatically increment in the database, if the persistence is done well, I should have an id when I appear with out the console.

```
<body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <%
       Outils o = new Outils();
       o.setDesignation("hammers");

       EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Test_EclipseLinkPU");
       UserTransaction utx = (UserTransaction) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/UserTransaction");

       OutilsJpaController o_ctrl = new OutilsJpaController(utx, emf);
       o_ctrl.create(o);

       out.println("this is the id of hammer " + o.toString());
    %>
</body>
```

and I get as result: Outils[ id=null ].

I have no error or on glassfish even less about the debugger.

Ps : Here are the persistence.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="Test_EclipseLinkPU" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>test_data_source</jta-data-source>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties/>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Thank you for your future is in your answers and listening for any additional information.

Comment: Can you show the implementation of OutilsJpaController.create and also the source of the entity Outils?

Comment: As worries about not cluttering I gave them in the implementation blue links.

Comment: Don't see anything wrong, did you check in the DB whether the object actually is persisted in the DB and EclipseLink just didn't fill in the id? For IDENTITY the values are generated by the DB so it might be that EclipseLink is not reading the id back.

Comment: I have checked the database, but it is empty. I really do not know what to do. Do you think this is a good method to use JPAControllers?

Comment: Weird you should either have an error in your logs or there should be something in the DB. It is good to have your persistence stuff in a class and not directly in the page. Personally I would make that class as an EJB. Maybe enabling more logging will shed some light on the issue. Add the following properties to your persistence.xml <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE"/> <property name="eclipselink.logging.level.sql" value="FINE"/> <property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true"/>

Comment: I have this error: java.io.IOException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; Invalid content found from the element 'property' One of the values '{"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence":shared-cache-mode, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence":validation-mode, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence":properties}' is expected

Comment: I did what you said and mistakes are part of, that said I still had no persistence in the database.

Answer (score 0):

(Not really an answer but I couldn't show this in a comment)
To increase logging your persistence.xml should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="Test_EclipseLinkPU" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>test_data_source</jta-data-source>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level.sql" value="FINE"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to commit or flush the transaction before anything will be written to the database.  If you are using IDENTITY sequencing (I strongly recommend not using IDENTITY, use TABLE or SEQUENCE if db supports it), then the Id cannot be allocated until the insert occurs, so a persist() will not assign the Id (as it does for TABLE and SEQUENCE).

What does your create() method do?  How is your Id mapped?

Comment: 1- `utx.begin();` 2- `em = getEntityManager();` 3- `em.persist(outils);` 4- `utx.commit();`